Qu'est-ce qui & Qu'est-ce qu'il
Ce n'est pas une question concernant « qu'est-ce qui » et « qu'est-ce que », donc ceci ne répond pas à ma question.
Quelle est la différence entre « qu'est-ce qui arrive ? » et « qu'est-ce qu'il arrive ? »
Il semble que les deux ont le même sens, mais la structure de la grammaire est clairement différente. Selon ce que je connais, dans « qu'est-ce qui arrive ? », on demande quel sujet fait l'action, mais dans « qu'est-ce qu'il arrive ? », on demande ce qui est « arrivé » par le sujet, dans ce cas « il ».
Au début je pensais que c'était juste une autre orthographe acceptable puisque « qui » ressemble beaucoup à « qu'il », mais je vois que l'on peut aussi dire « Qui arrive ? » et « Que arrive-t-il ? » donc je suis perplexe ici.
La même observation avec « Qui se passe ? » et « Que se passe-t-il ? », mais le second n'a aucun sens pour moi car ici, suivant la logique, on demande pour le sujet ce qui fait l'action de se passer, mais la seconde question demande pour un objet qu' « il se passe ». Se passer n'est pas même un verbe transitif mais réfléchi.
Comment puis-je comprendre la logique se trouvant derrière cette construction ?

La réponse est déjà faite dans la réponse à cette question « Ce qui se passe » ou « ce qu'il se passe » ?. Les explications sont-elles suffisantes ? La réponse mentionne le cas de arriver et d'autres verbes aussi.

« Qui se passe ? »  ne peut pas se dire. Les alternatives sont « Que se passe-t-il ? » et la question avec est-ce que donne « Qu'est-ce qui se passe ? » ou « Qu'est-ce qu'il se passe ? ».

@None Merci c'est suffisant. J'avais pensé que la distinction entre qui et qu'il existait pour tous les verbes, mais ça semble ne pas être le cas. La distinction est limitée aux certains verbes tels que se passer, arriver, plaire, etc.


je vois que l'on peut même dire « Qui arrive ? » et « Que arrive-t-il ? » donc je suis confus ici.


« Qui arrive ? » ou « Qui est-ce qui arrive ? » sont des questions qui servent à demander le nom d'une (ou de plusieurs) personne(s) qui est (sont) sujet du verbe arriver¹. Le verbe est ici utilisé dans un emploi personnel, c'est à dire qu'il peut avoir des sujets à toutes les personnes (je, tu, il(s), nous etc...)

« Que arrive-t-il ? » n'existe pas. Il faut faire l'élision du e à cause de la voyelle qui commence le mot suivant. Le e disparait et est remplacé par une apostrophe.

Qu'arrive-il ? Qu'est-ce qui arrive ? Qu'est-ce qu'il arrive ?
sont trois questions qui veulent dire exactement la même chose². Il s'agit du verbe arriver dans un emploi impersonnel, c'est à dire qu'il ne peut se conjuguer qu'à la 3ᵉ personne du singulier. Et il est synonyme de se passer, se produire, avoir lieu.



La même observation avec « Qui se passe ? » et « Que se passe-t-il ? », mais le seconde ne fait aucun sens pour moi


Se passer est un verbe pronominal mais on ne dira dans le sens où tu l'emploies ici qu'il est réfléchi parce qu'il n'y a pas de sujet qui agit sur lui-même.  Quand on dit je ne sais pas ce qui se passe ou qu'est ce qui se passe ? ou qu'est ce qu'il se passe ? il s'agit de l'emploi impersonnel du verbe se passer et est synonyme de arriver, se produire...

À ne pas confondre avec cet autre emploi du verbe se passer, qui veut dire : vivre sans, exemple : « Trop de gens ne peuvent pas se passer de voiture³ ».

Pour ce qui est de la présence de ce qui ou ce qu'il une réponse a déjà été faite « Ce qui se passe » ou « ce qu'il se passe » ?.


¹ Who's coming?
² What's happening?
³ can't do without 
